# Add custom compilation error on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

i am trying to find a way to add custom code errors to visual studio

for example

i want to prevent the use of `==` operator on strings parameters
and enforce the use of equals string method instead

so if a programmer will write the following code

```
string myString = ....

if(myString == "the string" ) - this line will have a compilation error
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Custom Roslyn code analyzer _probably_ may help, but it is not an easy task to implement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i've found a nice way of doing that using resharper 
with custom pattern

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/08/19/highlighting-custom-patterns-with-resharper/